# Float does't return on it's place. Responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-float

So I have to menus `ul's` one is not floated (left) and the other is floated to the right. The  problem is that the right one does not return on it's origin place after resizing the browser window.

**Preview**: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4uGnA/)
**Image:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqX6f.png

---

**HTML**:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<ul class="menu">
    <li>Option1</li>
    <li>Option2</li>
    <li>Option3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="menu right">
    <li>Option4</li>
    <li>Option5</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

---

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper
{
    width: 100%;
}

.menu
{
    display: inline-block;
}

@media (max-width: 399px)
{
    .menu
    {
        display: block;
    }        
}


@media (min-width: 400px)
{
   .right
    {
        float:right;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine on Firefox but in webkit, you need to float that and put a clear on the menu:

### http://jsfiddle.net/UTCE6/

```
.wrapper
{
    width: 100%;
}
.menu
{
    display: inline-block;
}

@media (max-width: 399px)
{
    .menu
    {
        display: block;
        clear:both;
        float:left;
    }        
}


@media (min-width: 400px)
{
    .right
        {
            float:right;
}
}
```

Comment: It worked also in IE. So Webkit is perhaps a little special because it somehow reserves the whole area for `block` elements in such way that it setting the element to the `inline-block` display doesn't clear that previously created area out. Or the Webkits `block` reserves the area normally, but it's perhaps the `inline-block` that does not do it's job (clearing out the whole space). In your example, that composition of properties reserves that space in such way that it gets simply cleared out or `display-block` is able to clear it out. Either way they should consider it as a bug. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using it like simple ?

```
.wrapper
{
    width: 100%;
}
.left{
    float:left;

}
.right{

    float:right;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/samithaHewawasam/c4AVS/)

Comment: Because I don't want it to float right at some point at all. And at another point I want it to float again. If you will resize the one I have prepared you, you will notice that on `399px` the right float will stop floating at once, and the menu will become a `block` object instead an `inline-block`.